# Checking list of material requirements availability

Tags: c#, linq

Models :

```
MaterialTemplate{
    int id,
    MaterialType materialType,
    int length,
    int width,
    int complexity
}

Material{
    int id,
    MaterialType materialType,
    int length,
    int width,
    int complexity,
    int saleType
}
```

I have 
`List<MaterialTemplate> requiredMaterialTemplates`;

***I would like to check if each required material template is available in Material table with 2x availability, where '2x' is configurable.***

I can achieve this by looping over `requiredMaterialTemplates` and checking one by one with linq query but is there any way to check all the `requiredMaterialTemplates` at once with linq(1 query to SQL).

Also, how can we get number of materials required for each material template if provided availability is 2x without looping every template in `requiredMaterialTemplates`.

Example:

Required materials with Availability value as 2x

```
MaterialTemplateId:1,MaterialType:"Bronze",Complexity:"Solid"
MaterialTemplateId:2,MaterialType:"Silver",Complexity:"Solid",Length:10
```

Materials in db

```
1,"Bronze",10,5,"Solid","Limited"
2,"Bronze",20,6,"Solid","Limited"
3,"Silver",10,5,"Solid","Limited"
4,"Copper",10,5,"Solid","Limited"
```

Result should be

```
MaterialTemplateId, Required Count
1,0
2,1
```

Comment: Does MaterialTemplate have an id of the Material item or something? How you can get the Material asociated to it?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @AlbertoCh yes, it has Id as in the question edited.

Comment: @D-Shih Updated the question with sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `group by` to get all the materialType you have twice or more.
Something like this:

```
from m in Material
group m by m.MaterialType into grp
where grp.Count() > 1
select grp.Key
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right what you need:

```
from material in availableMaterials
join template in requiredMaterialTemplates 
  on new { material.materialType, material.length, material.width, material.complexity }
  equals new { template.materialType, template.length, template.width, template.complexity }
where material.quantity < 2
select material
```

Here I assume you have `List<Material> availableMaterials`.

Comment: @suraj13k, it depends from how to interpret records in `Material` table. I assume there is one record per material and `quantity` means how much this material we have. In this case my query will works.

Comment: Okay, Please check updated question with sample data and expected result. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Excuse me, but now I don't understand which criteria should be used for desired results. Why bronze's required count is 0 if we have 2 bronze's records in Materials table? In other words, what is criteria for the availability? Is it number of records, product of length and width or something more complicate?

Comment: criteria can be dynamic, one template might be having only length of 10 and other template might have length, width, etc. Yes this is complicated :(